# g++ and clang++ different behaviour using a using alias to define a method

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using

Trying to respond to another question, I've found that g++ and clang++ disagree about the following simple code

```
template <typename>
struct foo
 { void bar (); };

template <typename T>
using fooAlias = foo<T>;

template <typename T>
void fooAlias<T>::bar ()
 { }

int main ()
 {
 }
```

While clang++ compile, g++ gives the following error

```
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:26:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct foo<T>’
 void fooAlias<T>::bar ()
                        ^
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:19:8: note: declaration of ‘struct foo<T>’
 struct foo
        ^~~
```

The question, as usual, is: who's right? clang++ or g++?

I also observe that the disagreement is connected with the presence of template parameter.

Indeed both clang++ and g++ compile the following code

```
struct foo
 { void bar (); };

using fooAlias = foo;

void fooAlias::bar ()
 { }

int main ()
 {
 }
```

Comment: Your second program is invalid, because you are explicitly required to use the name of the class in the definition of the member: "If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator.".

Comment: This definition is correct: `void fooAlias::foo::bar() { }`

Comment: For the template case, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1979 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286 is relevant and they indicate that the intended direction may become that your first code is valid.

Comment: The issue report in #1979 indicates that your second snippet is correct, but I faild to see how, given the explicit rule that forbids it. I think above quoted rule should be clarified that any name that refers to the class's type is allowed, if that's actually the intent.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb A type alias which names a possibly cv-qualified class type is a _class-name_ ([class.name]/5), but I agree "its class name" sounds more like the unique name in the _class-head_ than just any _class-name_.

Comment: @aschepler the spec usually keeps a clear distinction about a class' name and simply some identifier that refers to that class. For example an unnamed class has no name. It's therefore absurd that this compiles aswell on those compilers: `struct { void f(); } L; typedef decltype(L) foo; void foo::f() { }`.

Comment: @aschepler [class.name]/5 is gone in the latest drafts and now simply is http://eel.is/c++draft/class#name-5 . Do you know the reason or which paper did it?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Interesting. I don't know why that is.

Comment: For the template case there's also [temp.class]/3 "The template argument list following the class template name in the member definition shall name the parameters in the same order as the one used in the template parameter list of the member." And a specialization of an alias template may be a _class-name_ in C++17 (not current draft), but the alias template's name is never said to be a class template name, so that sentence isn't satisfied by the example.